# How can I use firebase alongside a primary database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, firebase

I want to leverage Firebase's real-time syncing features but use it as a secondary database. How would such an architecture be possible? In this scenario, a PostgreSQL or similar database would be used as the primary store, and firebase is used for real-time syncing and delivery of data to clients.

This is beneficial where for example in any case that firebase goes down, my service would still be running and only lose its real-time sync features, as opposed to going down completely. Or in any other scenario of difficulty using firebase, there is an in-house copy of data to turn to.

Ideally firebase would be the real-time eventual consistency store, whereas the data gets stored into the SQL database in parallel.

Is this a possible scenario, and are there any example architectures?

Thanks

Comment: See a.o. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853908/how-to-keep-firebase-in-sync-with-another-database?rq=1#comment29518476_17853908 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26611107/mysql-authoritative-database-combined-with-firebase?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mySQL authoritative database - combined with Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26611107/mysql-authoritative-database-combined-with-firebase)